# jQuery stop timeout when mouse on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have class:

```
<ul class="topStatsWrapper">
    <li><a href="">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="">link</a></li>
</ul>
```

This ul class updates every 3sec. How can I stop updating when mouse in ul class? When mouse leave from `.topStatsWrapper` then start settimeout again. Thanks.

```
initialize: function() {
    window.setTimeout( _.bind( this.updateStats, this, true ), 3 * 1000);
},
```

FULL CODE http://pastebin.com/nGnfaeN5

Comment: What does `_` do in your case?

Comment: @motanelu IDK, I'm developing IPS4 hook. Maybe there you can find something? `;( function($, _, undefined){
 "use strict";`

Comment: What's at the end, when you close the IIFE?

Comment: The function `updateStats()` must be creating a timeout as well, or it would only update once and then stop.  Without seeing that as well there's no way to answer.

Comment: @Archer http://pastebin.com/nGnfaeN5 full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not too sure if we have enough info to disseminate a proper answer here. Firstly I would declare your setTimeout as a variable that I could clear on the mouse over of your class.

```
var timer; // set this globally

// this is from within your function
initialize: function() {
    timer = setTimeout( _.bind( this.updateStats, this, true ), 3 * 1000);
},
```

Then use an event

```
$(document).on("mouseover", ".myclass", function(){
    timer.clearTimeout();
});
```

So use a setInterval instead:

```
var timer; // set this globally

// this is from within your function
initialize: function() {
    timer = setInterval( function(){ ... your code ... }, 3000);
},
```

Then use an event

```
$(document).on("mouseover", ".myclass", function(){
    timer.clearInterval();
});
```

Comment: It's not an interval - it's a timeout.  As soon as `this.updateStats` creates another timeout (which it must do or it would only run once) your global var becomes irrelevant.

Comment: hmm. How can I start this timeout?

Comment: @Archer yes I have two timeouts. One with `this.updateStats` second with `that.updateStats`

Comment: Yes, but I thought he wanted a way to stop the timeout?  The global gets overwritten every 3 seconds so if he wanted to stop the timer 2 seconds in this is how he would do it.

Comment: So if you are looking to start the timeout, I would change this to an setInterval.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `updateStats` function to this...

```
updateStats: function() {

    if (window._noUpdate === true) return;

    var that = this, update;
    this.showLoading( true );

    update = $.when( update,
        that.ajax( 'getTopics', null, '.newestThreads' ),
        that.ajax( 'getPosts', {limit: JSON.stringify([0, 3])}, '.newestPosts' )
    );

    update.done( function() {
        that.showLoading();
        window.setTimeout( _.bind( that.updateStats, that, true), that.interval * 1000);
    });

}
```

and change your `initialize` function to this...

```
initialize: function() {
    this.interval = parseInt($('.topStatsWrapper').attr('data-topstats-interval'));
    window.setTimeout( _.bind( this.updateStats, this, true ), 3 * 1000);
    $("body").on("hover", ".topStatsWrapper",
        function() {
            window._noUpdate = true;
        },
        function() {
            window._noUpdate = false;
        }
    });
},
```

This will set a global variable (`_noUpdate`) which signifies whether or not your cursor is hovering over the ul.  If it's set to `true` then the update function will simply exit without doing anything.

Comment: it is not updating now

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $document is not defined

Comment: It should be `$(document)`.  Make sure you've copied & pasted the above code correctly.

Comment: So that error message is gone now then.  Do you have any errors now?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $document is not define... I think it is IPS4 javascript, but similar to jQuery, there isn't $document

Comment: Is that definitely the line of code in the initialize function that I posted above?

Comment: Try changing it to `$("body")` as I have done above.  If that doesn't work then there's something conflicting with jQuery.

Comment: changed. I've added `alert(window._noUpdate);` and It everytime alerts undefined

Comment: Can you please check for errors in the console now that you've made that change?

Comment: Everything ok in console

Comment: look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/ECYD4/ I'm done with this, but now when I hover my class, code stops and do not work again, until i restart page